# How can i update <commandbutton> param with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, commandbutton, commandlink

I need to update from prompt 1 param in , but i get all the time a a JavaScript error "Cannot set property 'value'".

**I need to set the "rejectReason" param to what the user has written in prompt** and them to submit the action.

So Here's the code please help me to assign the variable to the param

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!processRejectButton}" onclick="rejectCandidate();" oncomplete="return location.reload();" value="Reject Candidate" id="theCommandLink">
      <apex:param name="approveId" assignTo="{!approveId}" value="{!c.con.ID}"/>
      <apex:param name="rejectReason" assignTo="{!rejectReason}" value="text" id="rejectReason"/>
   </apex:commandButton>
</apex:form>

<script>
    function rejectCandidate(){
      var missing = prompt("Enter reject reason details", "aaaa");

        if (missing != null && missing != "") {
           document.getElementById('{!$Component.rejectReason}').value = missing;
        }else{  
           alert("Please enter missing info details");
        }
   }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're half right here.

What you'll need to do is take the `<apex:param>` markup outside of the `<apex:commandButton>`. The button should then only call a JavaScript method, passing in the Id of the Contact(?). It shouldn't have an action:

```
<apex:commandButton onclick="rejectCandidate({!c.con.ID});" value="Reject Candidate" id="theCommandLink" />
```

Your `rejectCandidate()` method is fine as is, however it should do one more thing which is call a `<apex:actionFunction>` that passes in the parameters to the controller.

For example:

```
<script>
  function rejectCandidate(contactId){
    var missing = prompt("Enter reject reason details", "aaaa");

    if (missing != null && missing != "") {
       document.getElementById('{!$Component.rejectReason}').value = missing;
    }else{  
       alert("Please enter missing info details");
    }

    doRejectCandidate(
      missing,
      contactId
    );
  }
</script>
```

Alls we've really done to your JavaScript is add the latter part: something that calls `doRejectCandidate()` and passes in two `String` values (missing and contactId). "missing" is generated from the function you've already written, "contactId" is passed in from the button.

Finally, you'll just need to have an `<apex:actionFunction>` with the name `doRejectCandidate` that then assigns the parameters and calls the action you initially set in your button.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="doRejectCandidate" action="{!processRejectButton}">
      <apex:param name="missing" value="" />
      <apex:param name="contactId" value="" />
  </apex:actionFunction>
```

This will pass to the controller as a GET request, meaning you can then access the values of `missing` and `contactId` in your `processRejectButton()` method as below:

```
String missing = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('missing');
String contactId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('contactId');
```

Comment: Thanx, but i get this error: "<apex:actionFunction> may  not be used within an iterable component.
        You can use <apex:param> to define parameters for the function and pass iteration-specific values via the parameters."

Comment: An iterable component would be something like `apex:pageBlockTable` or `apex:Repeat`. You need to move the `apex:actionFunction` out of that loop.

Comment: but it needs to be in a <form> tag. can i  place it in another form?

Comment: The `apex:actionFunction` nor your JavaScript function need to repeat. The `apex:commandButton` will call your JS passing in the Id to your JS.

Comment: all the buttons are in a list that genarated by the system. so for each contact there is a button.

Comment: @Eli That's fine, the button can be in an iterable component, the `apex:actionFunction` doesn't need to be though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [apex:actionfunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) with parameter

```
<apex:commandButton onclick="rejectCandidate('{!c.con.ID}'); return false;" oncomplete="return location.reload();" value="Reject Candidate" id="theCommandLink" />
<apex:actionFunction action="{!processRejectButton}" name="processRejection" >
    <apex:param name="approveId" assignTo="{!approveId}" value=""/>
    <apex:param name="rejectReason" assignTo="{!rejectReason}" value="" id="rejectReason"/>
</apex:actionFunction>

<script>
    function rejectCandidate(var conId){
      var missing = prompt("Enter reject reason details", "aaaa");

        if (missing != null && missing != "") {
             processRejection(conId, missing);
        }else{  
             alert("Please enter missing info details");
        }
   }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of need we can use `<apex:actionFunction/>`.

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:commandbutton value="Reject Candidate" id="theCommandLink" onclick="return rejectCandidate('{!c.con.ID}');"/>
    <apex:actionfunction name="rejectCandidateAction" action="{!processRejectButton}" oncomplete="return location.reload();" >
      <apex:param name="approveId" assignTo="{!approveId}" value="{!c.con.ID}"/>
      <apex:param name="rejectReason" assignTo="{!rejectReason}" value="text" id="rejectReason"/>
   </apex:commandButton>
</apex:form>

<script>
    function rejectCandidate(conId){
      var missing = prompt("Enter reject reason details", "aaaa");

        if (missing != null && missing != "") {
           rejectCandidateAction(conId,'missing'); // because you have defined two params
        }else{  
           alert("Please enter missing info details");
        }
        return false; // prevent page reload by button
   }    
</script>
```

So, here the recommendation is to understand `<apex:actionfunction/>`. I used `actionFunction` `name` attribute to call it via Javascript.